# Hibernate object duplication

Tags: hibernate, orm

For example, I have the following db of two tables: Home and Person. There is one-to-many relationship between these tables. In one home many people live.

Now, let assume the following situation. I load one person from a db as a result I load a home in which this person lives. Then I load another person which lives in the same home. The question is what I am loading: a new home object or the same object which was loaded for the first person? Why?

Answer (score 1):

The same Home object. Hibernate keeps track, by PRIMARY KEY, of which objects it already has on hand, and when the Person constructor comes to fill in the Home, a reference to the already existing object will be used.

On the other hand, you should note that Home maybe getting fetched "lazily", in which case only a proxy (placeholder) for this Home will be a field in both Persons.

Comment: How long hibernate stores this history? What is the scope?

Comment: Suggest you read up on Hibernate Sessions and Transactions. In this case, Session lifetime unless you do some detaching and re-attaching by hand.